# Unable to get NLog to send fields as numbers/ints/longs from code

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nlog, graylog

Our tack is c# .net 4.7 logging through NLog library to a "Graylog" GELF input which of course is storing them in an elasticsearch cluster.

The application utilizes logging heavily, but EVERYTHING is sent through as strings - no matter if it was something other than a string in code.

I want to be able send my custom logger properties as their true data types so that I can aggregate on my statistical number fields.

I DO NOT want to constrain my developers and do this with scripted fields, or pre-mapping an index in elasticsearch - in fact, graylog manages my index for me. Nor do I want to utilize graylog pipeline processor - my poor graylog does enough work. I want them to be able to send stat data as their real data types and have them mapped as "long" or "number".

A code snippet from my stuff:

```
public void InfoExtended2(String Message, Dictionary<string, int> extrafields, [CallerMemberName] string callerMethodName = "", [CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = "", [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
        {
            var fileName = callerFilePath.Substring(callerFilePath.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1).Replace(".cs", "");
            var caller = $"{fileName}.{callerMethodName}()Line:{sourceLineNumber}";
            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(caller);

            if (!(extrafields.Count == 0))
            {
                foreach (var field in extrafields)
                {
                    string mykey = field.Key.ToString();
                    extrafields.TryGetValue(field.Key, out int myvalue);
                    //be careful whats in object! 
                    if (!logger.Properties.ContainsKey(mykey)) { logger.Properties.Add(mykey, "{@myvalue}"); } else { logger.Properties[mykey] = "{@myvalue}"; }
                }
            }

            logger.Info()
                .Message(Message)
                .Property("ComeOnNow3", 87)

                .Write();

            // Create the LogEventInfo object
            //LogEventInfo logEvent = new LogEventInfo();

            // Now add the event characteristics
            //logEvent.Properties["EventCode"] = 2222;
            //logEvent.Level = NLog.LogLevel.Info;
            //logEvent.Properties["EventCode]."]
            //logEvent.Message = "My Message";
            ////logEvent.Exception = ex;
            //logger.Log(logEvent);

            //logger.Info("{@Message}", new Dictionary<string, int> { { "key1", 1 }, { "key2", 2 } }); // dict. Result:  Test "key1"=1, "key2"=2

        }
```

I've tried a few different ways there with no luck.

If I make a POST GELF call myself with JSON fields representing ints instead of strings, it works. My field is brand new to the index and when I go check the mapping it comes back as a long. I want my code to do that.

Test GELF Call:

```
{
  "version": "1.1",
  "host": "example.org",
  "short_message": "A short message that helps you identify what is going on",
  "full_message": "Backtrace here\n\nmore stuff",
  "timestamp": 1385053862.3072,
  "level": 1,
  "_user_id": 9001,
  "_some_info": "foo",
  "_some_env_var": "bar"
}
```

Resulting mapping for user id:

```
          "user_id" : {
            "type" : "long"
```

What our nlog target currently looks like:

```
<targets>
      <target name="gelftcp"
      type="gelftcp"
      facility="Custom Facility"
      remoteaddress="192.168.95.15"
      remoteport="12201"
      layout="${longdate}${newline}type: ${level:uppercase=true}${newline}class: ${logger}${newline}stacktrace: ${stacktrace}${newline}error message: ${message}${newline}exception: ${exception:format=tostring,data:maxinnerexceptionlevel=10}">
        <parameter name="logged_at" layout="${longdate}" />
        <parameter name="type" layout="${level:uppercase=true}" />
            <parameter name="class" layout="${logger}" />
        <parameter name="CustomInt" layout="${event-properties:item=CustomInt}" as="number" />
            <parameter name="stacktrace" layout="${stacktrace}" />
            <parameter name="error_message" layout="${message}" />
        <parameter name="ComeOnNow3" layout="${event-properties:item=ComeOnNow3} " />
            <parameter name="exception" layout="${exception:format=tostring,data:maxinnerexceptionlevel=10}" />
        <attribute name="eventProperties" encode="false" >
          <layout type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true"  maxRecursionLimit="2"/>
        </attribute>
          <variable name="ComeOnNow2" value ="${event-context:ComeOnNow2}" />

      </target>
```

Take it easy on me, I'm not the original author of this code. Just someone tasked with picking up slack & deploying in its current state.

**UPDATE:**
Tried the first suggestion. Even added the field I'm testing:

```
<field name="ComeOnNow3" layout="${threadid}" type="System.Int32" />
```

Attempted this log entry:

```
logger.Info()
                .Message(Message)
                .Property("ComeOnNow3", 87)
                .Write();
```

My mapping still comes back as "keyword".

***SOLVED:***

The trick was to switch to Http instead of Tcp.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "gelftcp". Then you can try out GelfLayout instead:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.GelfLayout

You can combine it with the TCP network-target:

```
<nlog>
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Layouts.GelfLayout" />
  </extensions>

  <targets async="true">
    <target type="Network" name="gelftcp" address="tcp://192.168.95.15:12201" newLine="true" lineEnding="Null">
        <layout type="GelfLayout" facility="MyFacility">
            <field name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" type="System.Int32" />
        </layout>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="gelftcp" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

It also has some automatic conversion logic for simple NLog LogEventInfo.Properties (Decimal + Double + Integer + Boolean)

More examples can be found here: https://github.com/farzadpanahi/NLog.GelfLayout

Comment: I will give it a shot

Comment: Took your suggestion and changed to this successfully and logging. Not much success. Update in original

Comment: Solved! OP Updated